# Source of \bar{} accent in math mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode, accents

I have a font that I have installed with `fontinst` in `psnfss` and which I use for math italic. But it is clear from the PDF files generated with that font that the bar accent in math mode is not generated from the overbar character in the font (they clearly don't have the same shape), and I don't want to use `\overline` to achieve the same effect.

I do the usual

- `latex fontinst.sty`
- `\latinfamily{eaq}{}\bye`
- `for i in *.pl ; do pltotf $i ; done`
- `for i in *.vp; do vptovf $i ; done`
- copy the file to the right directories (including the `.fd`) in the the  TeX live kpathsea tree
- add the right entries to `pdftex.map` (yes, I know I should be using the `updmap` machinery do to this)

It's clear that the PDF files generated with this routine that the overbar accent is not the one included in the font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `\bar` in LaTeX kernel is in `fontmath.ltx`:

```
% ...
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
% ...
\DeclareMathAccent{\bar}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"16}
% ...
```

That is to say, `\bar` is a math accent from a symbol in font (in NFSS) of `OT1` encoding, `cmr` family, `m` series and `n` shape. The symbol is the 0x16th (22th) glyph in the font.

To understand this definition clearly, you may need to read [`fntguide`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fntguide) and [`encguide`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/encguide) documents carefully, and of course [`source2e`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/source2e).

Then you can define a proper `\bar` for your own font (you know the details).

You may also be interested in package [`fonttable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fonttable) and [`accents`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/accents).